# How can I simplify a correlation code in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This is my df:

```
                  date                     z         x                    y 
   <dttm>                               <dbl>    <dbl>                <dbl> 
 1 2019-01-01 00:00:00                   1333  3339072.         456700000000 
 2 2019-02-01 00:00:00                    915  4567582.         904600000000 
 3 2019-03-01 00:00:00                   1433  7887962.         247900000000 
 4 2019-04-01 00:00:00                   1444  3454559.         905700000000 
 5 2019-05-01 00:00:00                   1231  9082390.         245600000000 
 6 2019-06-01 00:00:00                    346   781224.         346700000000
```

How can I simplify this code to a for loop?

```
df %>%
filter(year(df$date) == 2017) %>%
mutate(correlation = cor(x, y))

df %>%
filter(year(df$date) == 2018) %>%
mutate(correlation = cor(x, y))

df %>%
filter(year(df$date) == 2019) %>%
mutate(correlation = cor(x, y))

df %>%
filter(year(df$date) == 2020) %>%
mutate(correlation = cor(x, y))
```

That's what I tried so far, but I've got some NAs:

```
years <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)
for (y in years) {
  df %>%
    filter(date == y) %>%
    mutate(correlation = cor(x, y))
    print(df$correlation[y])
}
```

My desired output would be something like

```
[1] 2017: 0.23
[1] 2018: -0.38
[1] 2019: 0.40
[1] 2020: 0.15
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the correlation by year you might want to be able to turn the dttm column into something that allows us to do equality by year. We can use the year function in lubridate for that, the code should work then.

```
library(lubridate)

df$year <- year(df$date)

for (y in unique(df$year)){
  df %>%
    filter(year == y) %>%
    mutate(correlation = cor(x, y)) %>%
    print(unique(correlation))
}
```

Alternatively we can be a little more succinct and do the following transformation with a group_by.

```
yearDf <- df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(x, y))

print(yearDf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group_by` `year` and calculate correlation for `x` and `y` in each `year`. Also since correlation would give you only one number for each `year` it is better to `summarise` instead of `mutate` because `mutate` would repeat the same value for all rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(year = year(date)) %>% summarise(correlation = cor(x, y))
```